# oozie spark action with spark2 code fails with "jackson version too old 2.4.4"

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I am trying to run an oozie spark action that runs spark 2.x code. Followed the steps mentioned in Hortonwork's HDP documentation, however, the spark action fails with error "jackson version too old 2.4.4".
Spark2 oozie sharelib jars have 2.6.5 version of jackson jars, but oozie's oozie-sharelib jars have 2.4.4 version of jackson jars.
Hence, sometimes the job runs fine but sometimes it fails citing the version mismatch or NoSuchMethodExists exception (again due to mismatched jars ).

I dont want to delete the 2.4.4 version jars from oozie' oozie sharelib, but wondering why these jars are added to the classpath when spark action is running. Is there a way to only add jars from /user/oozie/share/lib//spark2 and restrict any other jars from getting added to classpath ?